# How to make notification icon in android

Tags: android, icons

i wanted to create a notification icon in my application which displays any new event that occurs in my application as similar to a new message or new mail as you find in android. can you guys help me with a link or share your own ideas to how to implement this..

Comment: Is this a question on how to make the icon itself? Or how to include an icon in a notification?

Comment: you can do as: Notification notification=new Notification(icon, text, when); where icon is int icon=R.drawable.ic_launcher; pass whichever icon you want to keep in notifiaction

Comment: This tutorial will help u in creating a notification: [Android notification tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html)

Comment: I need an icon where i can pass a value that will be displayed as no of notifications or no of events to be viewd, similar as you see in facebook

Comment: Tried anything? And no offense but your english is bad, maybe if you added some code and stated what you have tried, then we could help you more easily.

Answer (score 0):

The prefered way of creating `Notification` now is using the `Notification.Builder` class. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) you can find the documentation and an example of using this class. It has a `setSmallIcon()` method which is just what you need. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found a Great Tutorial on Notifications  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm This has much more detail but For a Simple Icon...

Copy your notification icon to your drawable folders

Add the following Variables to your Activity

```
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private int notificationID = 100;
```

Add the Following Methods

```
// Start the Notification Icon
protected void displayNotification() {
    Log.i("Start", "notification");

    /* Invoking the default notification service */
    NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);    
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fl_notification);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Flashlight");

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    /* notificationID allows you to update the notification later on. */
    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());

 }


// Stop the Notification Icon
 protected void cancelNotification() {
    Log.i("Cancel", "notification");
    mNotificationManager.cancel(notificationID);
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use Toast. A toast notification is a message that pops up on the surface of the window.
Example:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

You can see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/index.html for more detailed.

Comment: What has Toast to do with this question?